# wcf service is not defined after converting from web site to web application project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2015

I get a javascript reference error wcf service is "not defined" after using Visual Studio 2015 to convert from web site to web application project

The service belongs to the same site/project as the client.  There is no service reference because the original web site didn't have a service reference.  It was done using the web.config.

The client proxy code isn't generated (or maybe generates a blank proxy) and so the javascript call to the service errors with 'not defined'

Comment: Note, the prior developer made this in 2009 and put the service in the web site, that is, it is a single web application.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace on my service was CHANGED by the automatic upgrade from website to web application.  Edit the svc file and make sure the service attribute has the new namespace of your app.

```
Service="newAppNamespace.oldWebsiteNamespace.classname"
```